# printing alphabets using star pattern side by side in C

Tags: c

I am trying to print the initials of My First Name "S S" using * pattern in C. However the patterns are printed one after the other. Is there any way to print the alphabets using * pattern one at the side of the other with a little space in between. I do not want to allot a very big box for both the alphabets. I want to code for individual alphabets and put them side by side with some space in between. My Code and out our is given below:

```
int k,l,i,j;
for(k=1;k<=7;k++){
    for(l=1;l<=4;l++){
        if(k==1 && l<=4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(k>=2 && k<=3 && l==1){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(k==4 && l<=4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(k>=5 && k<=6 && l==4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(k==7 && l<=4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else{
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
for(i=1;i<=7;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=4;j++){
        if(i==1 && j<=4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i>=2 && i<=3 && j==1){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==4 && j<=4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i>=5 && i<=6 && j==4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else if(i==7 && j<=4){
            printf("*");
        }
        else{
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
****
*
*
****
   *
   *
****
****
*
*
****
   *
   *
****
```

However, I want my expected output to be:

```
****      ****
*         *
*         *
****      ****
   *         *
   *         *
****      ****
```

Comment: Will you accept any answer that has reasonably simple code and prints the expected output?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when code-formatted text would do.  abelenky already edited your quesiton to be readable and then you messed it up.  I think you should revert to revision 2.

Comment: With just very basic coding I want to code for individual alphabets in * patter and put them side by side with white space in between I don't want to allot a very big box instead small codes for each alphabets and printing them side by side. Thank You!

Comment: sorry I am new to this site, while manually pasted the output the site was showing some dots instead of the actual pattern I thought it would create some confusion so I edited the same

Comment: You can select your star patterns and click the "Code Sample" button to format them properly.  This adds 4 spaces at the beginning of each line so that it will be formatted as code.  Even though it's not technically code, this will make the output be legible.  Use the preview to make sure your question looks good before posting.

Comment: Don't add images when text can be used instead.

Comment: I guess now the output is perfectly understandable.Kindly help me how can I code for Individual alphabets with * pattern and put them side by side with white space without occupying and allowing a very big box and having code for each alphabet.

Comment: If you want to write your name say with `NxN` matrix of stars, then prepare a matrix for each letter. Then write them to show up side by side.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing when approaching problems like this is to decompose your code in smaller pieces, using functions and/or typedefs or structs to organize things.  In your case, you can easily separate the "knowledge" of how to print stars and spaces for your letters from the main code (which knows which letters to print in which order) using functions.  Refactoring you code that way, we get:

```
void S(int k, int l) {
   if(k==1 && l<=4){
        printf("*");
    }
    else if(k>=2 && k<=3 && l==1){
        printf("*");
    }
    else if(k==4 && l<=4){
        printf("*");
    }
    else if(k>=5 && k<=6 && l==4){
        printf("*");
    }
    else if(k==7 && l<=4){
        printf("*");
    }
    else{
        printf(" ");
    }
}

int main() {
    int k,l,i,j;
    for(k=1;k<=7;k++){
        for(l=1;l<=4;l++){
            S(k, l);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=1;i<=7;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=4;j++){
            S(i, j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can easily rewrite main to print the letters side by side

```
int main() {
    int k,l,i,j;
    for(k=1;k<=7;k++){
        for(l=1;l<=4;l++){
            S(k, l);
        }
        printf(" ");
        for(j=1;j<=4;j++){
            S(k, j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also extend this by writing different letters in different patterns (though having a function for each letter is somewhat verbose -- better would be to store the pixels for all letters in a data structure and print it that way)

Comment: Thank You Very Much! However am a beginner in C so I know up to loops and condition statements so I still don't properly get it, so I wanted the same output with just basic coding but anyways Thank You very Much!

Comment: IMO you should probably learn about functions before you learn about loops and conditionals, as they are more fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matrix for every character you want to print. It'll make printing easier. You run through each letter of the string to print for every row in the pattern.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWMAX 7
#define COLMAX 5
#define CSPACE 1
#define PATTERN '#'


char cCube [26][ROWMAX][COLMAX] = {
    {   {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // letter S
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
    },
    {   {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, // letter O
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}
    },
    {   {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, // letter D
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
    }, //so on for alphabets you want to use
};


int chIndex [256] = {0};

void print_pat_msg (const char* msg) {
    int mlen = strlen (msg);
    for (int ri = 0; ri < ROWMAX; ++ri) {
        for (int mi = 0; mi < mlen; ++mi) {
            int chi = chIndex[ (unsigned char) msg[mi]];
            for (int ci = 0; ci < COLMAX; ++ci)
                (cCube[chi][ri][ci]) ? putchar (PATTERN) : putchar (' ');
            for (int spi = 0; spi++ < CSPACE;) putchar (' ');
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main () {
    // if patterns are indexed alphabetically below initialisation can be omitted
    chIndex[ (unsigned char) 'S'] = 0;
    chIndex[ (unsigned char) 'O'] = 1;
    chIndex[ (unsigned char) 'D'] = 2;

    char message [] = "ODDS";
    print_pat_msg (message);
    return 0;
}
```

- This way you can design/customise the pattern for each letter with ease at one place. Code & pattern can be reused for other messages & names.
- Printing here works somewhat like a dot-matrix printer, striping across putting out pattern-line of each letter in the string one at a time.
- You can also replace `0`/`1` flags with pretty much any character to draw ASCII images. You just have to adjust the pattern array, which is easy to follow & change at will.
- Come to think of it, this is how fonts work at pixel level, patterns.

Comment: Some elaboration on why the OP would want to use patterns set up this way would improve this answer.

Comment: Perhaps something about how having it stored in lines means you can print lines of multiple letters "in parallel."

Answer (score -2):

My quickie solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const unsigned char S[] = {0xF0, 0x80, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x10, 0x10, 0xF0};

int main(void) {
    
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(S); ++i)
    {
        for(int b=7;b; --b)
        {
            printf("%c", "* "[!(S[i] & (1<<b))]);
        }
        for(int b=7;b; --b)
        {
            printf("%c", "* "[!(S[i] & (1<<b))]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5548KB
****   ****   
*      *      
*      *      
****   ****   
   *      *   
   *      *   
****   ****
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot! However am a beginner so I know up to loops and condition statement so I couldn't get it clearly anyways thank you very much

Comment: Some explanation would greatly improve this answer.